# How to find zookeeper configs path location

Tags: solr, zookeeper

I've setup a SOLR server with Zookeeper by followed the below link.
[SolrCloud-Helpers](https://github.com/jermdavis/SolrCloud-Helpers)

I have done the Solr and Zookeeper setup by using the powershell script by given the above link and I can see there are two Solr configs folder(Sitecore, xDB) has been created with managed schema under Config folder on Zookeeper Tree as shown below.

[image]

Now i would like to see the location of managed schema of xDB. I cannot find the location of the managed schema. If i want to modify something in the managed schema, I need the location.

Kindly someone assist me how to see the location to modify the schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can find location here `server\solr\configsets\sitecore_configs\conf` to update `managed-schema` file.

After update, run below command to deploy config:

```
solr zk upconfig -d sitecore_configs -n sitecore -z localhost:$zookeeperPort
```

Comment: I can see two separate managed schema file for Sitecore and XDB and also the XDB managed schema is different from the one which you mentioned (server\solr\configsets\sitecore_configs\conf\managed-schema)

Answer (score 0):

Download configset of a collection with command:

```
zkcli.bat -zkhost <zookeeper URL> -cmd downconfig -confdir <folder path to where config files to be downloaded> -confname <config name>
```

Then modify configurations. To upload the update config

```
zkcli.bat -zkhost <zookeeper URLs> -cmd upconfig -confdir <folder path where config files to be uploaded exist> -confname <config name>
```

After that, reload the collection from admin panel.

Btw, zkcli.bat exists in server/scripts/cloud-scripts folder of solr